# How to install Packet Tracer 6.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Tags: 14.04

Can you explain me how to install step-by-step? Why Can't I run packet tracer 6.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit? Please suggest me! Thanks

Answer (score 9):

To install packet tracer 6.2 on 14.04, [download this file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/j871uasb9or2ukb/Cisco+Packet+Tracer+6.2+for+Linux+-+Ubuntu+installation+-+Student+version.tar.gz) to your `/home` directory and extract it

```
tar -xzf ~/Cisco Packet Tracer 6.2 for Linux - Ubuntu installation - Student version.tar
```

Now change to the extracted directory

```
cd PacketTracer62Student
```

Now execute the installer

```
./install
```

Follow the on screen instructions, when you are done run

```
packettracer
```

Now your program will start.

As pointed out by the OP this is 32bit package, to run a 32bit package on a 64bit system, simply run this command to add the architecture

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this answer helped you please press the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others easily find the information, if not please feedback.

Comment: Mark, Thanks for your answer. But I can't run it because my OS is 64 bits. Do I need to install extra?? Please suggest me. Thank you!

Comment: @LaminAung Please see updated answer to rum 32bit packages on 64bit ubuntu :)

Comment: working like a charm!